# Read multiple notifications from GCM in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I need to create multiple statusbar notifications. When I pull down the statusbar, multiple notification icons should be displayed as a list. Each notification icon should show separate data to display on next page. How could I do this, remove notificaton also not working, please tell me any solutionpackage or share your views.

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
    Context context;
    public static  int NOTIFICATION_ID =(int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    //System.currentTimeMillis();
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

         if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

             if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    sendNotification(msg);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
         GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
        myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("Event tracker")
        .setContentText("Events received");
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    String[] events = new String[6];
    // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");

    // Moves events into the big view
    for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

        inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
    }
    // Moves the big view style object into the notification object.
    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);


        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        /* Even if the mode is set to "Sound & Vibration" in the phone, 
         * the status code that getRingerMode() returns is RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.
         */
        switch (am.getRingerMode()) 
        {
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
                break;
            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                break;
            default:
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
         }


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

      mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

      NOTIFICATION_ID++;

    }
    public void CancelNotification(Context ctx) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }


   }

   receiving activity

   TextView name;
    TextView deal;
    TextView valid;
    TextView address;
    JSONObject json;
@Override
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use different notification id for different Notification.
for achieve this you can use "long id = System.currentTimeMillis();"

Comment: i wrte same thing in above code but it is not working[public static  int NOTIFICATION_ID =(int) System.currentTimeMillis();]

Comment: public static  int NOTIFICATION_ID =(int) System.currentTimeMillis(); use this line in onHandleIntent(Intent intent) then  i think it should work.

Comment: thanks for response,i did same thing it is not working,it overrides previous data,if possible will u please check in your system